# enabling colors in the python interactive shell on OS/X

Tags: macos, python, terminal.app, iterm, .bash-profile

I have just modified my .bash_profile so as to have colors in iTerm and Terminal.

Now, I want to enable syntax highlighting for the Python interactive shell, IDLE-style.

How to do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org/) appears to do what you want.

> bpython is a fancy interface to the Python interpreter for Linux, BSD, OS X and Windows (with [some work](http://docs.bpython-interpreter.org/windows.html)). bpython is released under the MIT License. It has the following (special) features:

[image]

- In-line **syntax highlighting**
- Readline-like autocomplete with suggestions displayed as you type
- Expected parameter list for any Python function
- Send the code you've entered off to a pastebin
- Auto-indentation
  And more

---

Alternatives are [IPython](http://ipython.org/) or [DreamPie](http://www.dreampie.org/)

Comment: Or ipython. Both are fancier alternatives than the vanilla python interpreter.

Comment: @vtest I now added syntax highlighting feature to the ipython features list in the wiki table. Thank you.